# xslt mapping for same multiple source element to single target element

Tags: xml, xslt

Need your help for xslt mapping .
Suppose source is like below .

```
   <A>
   <B>
   <C>Test1</C>
   <D></D>
   </B>
   <B>
   <C>Test2</C>
   <D></D>
   </B>
   </A>
```

Where element B is unbounded ,lets my target xsd like below .

```
 <X>
<Y></Y>
 </X>
```

I want to map all the value of C element in Y element like that .

```
<X><Y>Test1,Test2</Y></X>
```

How can i implement ,need your help
Regards

Comment: With XSLT questions, please specify which version of XSLT you are using. It's usually much easier to produce an XSLT 2.0 answer but it's a waste of time if you're stuck on XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the options based on the XSLT version that you are using.

**XSLT 1.0**

In XSLT 1.0, you need to loop through the `<C>` elements and concatenate the values and `,` separator. As compared to XSLT 2.0, this one needs more coding.

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <X>
        <Y>
            <xsl:for-each select="B/C">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Y>
    </X>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

In XSLT 2.0, a much optimized approach is available, provided you are using a factory such as Saxon viz. `saxon9he.jar` in case of Java.

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <X>
        <Y>
            <xsl:value-of select="B/C" separator=", " />
        </Y>
    </X>
</xsl:template>
```

Both these templates provide the desired output.

```
<X>
   <Y>Test1, Test2</Y>
</X>
```